# Print JSON response from REST api in ionic

Tags: html, json, rest, ionic-framework

I'm trying to print a JSON response that I get from a RESTful API request like that:

```
products:Observable<any>;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation, public zone: NgZone, private auth: AuthService, public httpClient: HttpClient)
{

    this.products = this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product');
}
```

It works fine, indeed if I print result in console:

```
this.products
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('my data: ', data);
      });
```

the data is right.

But now, I don't know how to print them out onto a HTML page. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let p of (products | async)?.results">{{ p.productName}}
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Are there other ways to resolve the problem?

My JSON response is like that:

```
0: Object { idProduct: "1", productName: "Pasta", purchased: "0" }
​
1: Object { idProduct: "2", productName: "latte", purchased: "0" }
```

I have resolved the trouble. I want to post the solution to help other users in this bad situation.
Solution is so simple. I created a new typescript file called: 'rest-service' made up by:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
  }
  getUsers() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Now, in home.ts I've done that:

```
getUsers() {
    this.restProvider.getUsers()
      .then(data => {
        this.products = data;
        console.log(this.products);
      });
  }
```

And then, in the constructor, that:

```
this.getUsers();
```

In HTML side instead, the solution is very very simple:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let p of products"> {{ p.productName }}
```

However, thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

please try to convert products to array object. That may fix your problem.

```
this.products = this.products.json();
```

Comment: Excuse me, thank you for response but, what is: products? products object doesn't have any json() method

Comment: Sorry, I mean this.products

Comment: There is no json method anyway. I'm trying to do that:

Comment: this.products
      .subscribe((data: Response) => {
        this.products = data.json();
      });

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Looks like you found the solution. Normally I don't prefer doing `*ngFor` directly at a function

```
<!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of someFunction()">
```

but rather define a variable above the constructor, and then assign data. A separate file wouldn't be necessary, but can be useful if you are doing the same request over and over.

**TypeScript**

```
items: Array<any> = [];

constructor() {
  // ...
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.http.get('https://someurl.com/data').subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.items = data;
  }).catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong: ', err));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item.name }}
</ion-item>
```

***Old answer***

What happens if you just do following?

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let p of products">
```

Any reason why you are trying to access **.results** on the products-array?

If you get any errors in the console, please share them with us.

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: This is the error. I've tried also a static way like that:
this.samples = [
      {"date" : "Thursday 16 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class"},
      {"date" : "Tuesday 14 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class"},
      {"date" : "Friday 10 Mar","Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class"}]
And, if I do <ion-item *ngFor="let p of samples"> it works. Is so strange

Comment: I thought it could be that there is no parent in JSON response. On other posts i found this solution:
<ion-item *ngFor="let p of products.parent">{{ p.attribute }}
But here there is no parent